# Knock down walls in a maze

Tags: code-golf, maze

#### Rules:

In this game you start at the top of a rectangular grid of size N x M made up of walls and open spaces. The input is N lines of M characters, where a `.` specifies an open space and a `x` specifies a wall. Your program should output the smallest number K such that there exists a path from the top left corner to the bottom right corner (no diagonals) that crosses K walls.

For example, given the input:

```
..x..
..x..
xxxxx
..x..
..x..
```

your program should output `2`.

#### Other examples:

output `4`:

```
xxxxx
x.x.x
x.x.x
x..xx
```

output `0`:

```
.xxxxxxxx
.x...x...
.x.x.x.x.
.x.x...x.
...xxxxx.
```

output `6`:

```
xx
xx
xx
xx
xx
```

#### Extra tidbits:

If it makes your life easier, you can specify N and M as command line parameters.

Extra credit if you can have your program print out the path in some form or another.

Comment: :yawn: Dijkstra, with a heap which is a V[2][] and a counter.

Comment: @Peter Taylor But how short can you make that code?

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby 1.9 <strike>(235)</strike> <strike>(225)</strike> <strike>(222)</strike> (214)

I don't know if this is shorter than a program based on Dijkstra, but I figured I would try a different approach. This uses regex in a loop to mark each space with the minimal number of walls required to reach it.

```
w=".{#{/\s/=~s=$<.read}}?"
j="([.x])"
s[0]=v=s[0]<?x??0:?1
(d=v[-1];n=v.succ![-1]
0while(s.sub!(/#{j}(#{w+d})/m){($1<?x?d: n)+$2}||s.sub!(/(#{d+w})#{j}/m){$1+($2<?x?d: n)}))while/#{j}/=~q=s[-2]
p v.to_i-(q==n ?0:1)
```

Input is specified as a file on the command line, i.e.

```
> ruby1.9.1 golf.rb maze.txt
```

Ungolfed:

```
# read in the file
maze = $<.read

# find the first newline (the width of the maze)
width = /\s/ =~ maze

# construct part of the regex (the part between the current cell and the target cell)
spaces = ".{#{width}}?"

# construct another part of the regex (the target cell)
target = "([.x])"

# set the value of the first cell, and store that in the current wall count
maze[0] = walls = (maze[0] == "x" ? "1" : "0")

# loop until the goal cell is not "." or "x"
while /#{target}/ =~ (goal = s[-2])

  # store the current wall count digit and the next wall count digit, while incrementing the wall count
  current = walls[-1]; next = walls.succ![-1]

  # loop to set all the reachable cells for the current wall count
  begin

    # first regex handles all cells above or to the left of cells with the current wall count
    result = s.sub!(/#{target}(#{spaces + current})/m) {
      ($1 == 'x' ? next : current) + $2
    }

    # second regex handles all cells below or to the right of cells with the current wall count
    result = result || s.sub!(/(#{current + spaces})#{target}/m) {
      $1 + ($2 == 'x' ? next : current)
    }
  end while result != nil
end

# we reached the goal, so output the wall count if the goal was a wall, or subtract 1 if it wasn't
puts walls.to_i - (goal == next ? 0 : 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Python <s>406</s> <s>378</s> <s>360</s> <s>348</s> 418 chars**

```
import sys
d={}
n=0
for l in open(sys.argv[1]):
 i=0
 for c in l.strip():m=n,i;d[m]=c;i+=1
 n+=1
v=d[0,0]=int(d[0,0]=='x')
X=lambda *x:type(d.get(x,'.'))!=str and x
N=lambda x,y:X(x+1,y)or X(x-1,y)or X(x,y+1)or X(x,y-1)
def T(f):s=[(x,(v,N(*x))) for x in d if d[x]==f and N(*x)];d.update(s);return s
while 1:
 while T('.'):pass
 v+=1
 if not T('x'):break
P=[m]
s,p=d[m]
while p!=(0,0):P.insert(0,p);x,p=d[p]
print s, P
```

Simplified Dijkstra, since moves with weight are on `x` field. It is done in "waves", first loop with finding `.` fields touching front and set them on same weight, than once find `x` fields touching front and set them on `+1` weight. Repeat while there are no more unvisited fields.

At the end we know weight for every field.

Input is specified as a file on the command line:

```
python m.py m1.txt
```

**Update:** prints path.

Answer (score 2):

### Perl 5.10 (164)

```
undef$/;$_=<>;/\n/;$s="(.{$-[0]})?";substr$_,0,1,($n=/^x/||0);
until(/\d$/){1while s/([.x])($s$n)/$n+($1eq x).$2/se
+s/$n$s\K[.x]/$n+($&eq x)/se;$n++}
/.$/;print"$&\n"
```

Very much along the same lines as migimaru's solution, only with that extra Perl touch. 5.10 is needed for `\K` in `s///`.

Comment: Does this properly handle mazes that require passing through more than 9 walls?

Comment: @migimaru No. I could get it up to 45 or so with only a modest increase in characters, and up to a nearly-unlimited number with another small increase -- but it wouldn't be quite as pretty.

Answer (score 1):

C++ version (<del>610</del>  <del>607</del> <del>606</del> 584)

```
#include<queue>
#include<set>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>
#define S second
#define X s.S.first
#define Y s.S.S
#define A(x,y) f.push(make_pair(s.first-c,make_pair(X+x,Y+y)));
#define T typedef pair<int
using namespace std;T,int>P;T,P>Q;string l;vector<string>b;priority_queue<Q>f;set<P>g;Q s;int m,n,c=0;int main(){cin>>m>>n;getline(cin,l);while(getline(cin,l))b.push_back(l);A(0,0)while(!f.empty()){s=f.top();f.pop();if(X>=0&&X<=m&&Y>=0&&Y<=n&&g.find(s.S)==g.end()){g.insert(s.S);c=b[X][Y]=='x';if(X==m&&Y==n)cout<<-(s.first-c);A(1,0)A(-1,0)A(0,1)A(0,-1)}}}
```

Implements Dijkstra's algorithm.

Un-golfed:

```
#include<queue>
#include<set>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>

using namespace std;
typedef pair<int,int>P;
typedef pair<int,P>Q;

int main()
{
    int             m,n;
    string          line;
    vector<string>  board;

    cin >> m >> n;getline(cin,l);
    while(getline(cin,line))
    {
        board.push_back(line);
    }

    priority_queue<Q>   frontList;
    set<P>              found;
    frontList.push(make_pair(0,make_pair(0,0)));
    while(!frontList.empty())
    {
        Q s=frontList.top();
        frontList.pop();
        if(   s.second.first>=0
           && s.second.first<=m
           && s.second.second>=0
           && s.second.second<=n
           && found.find(s.second)==found.end()
        )
        {
            found.insert(s.second);
            int c=board[s.second.first][s.second.second]=='x';
            if(  s.second.first==m
              && s.second.second==n
            )
            {   cout<<-(s.first-c);
            }
            frontList.push(make_pair(s.first-c,make_pair(s.second.first+1,s.second.second)));
            frontList.push(make_pair(s.first-c,make_pair(s.second.first-1,s.second.second)));
            frontList.push(make_pair(s.first-c,make_pair(s.second.first,s.second.second+1)));
            frontList.push(make_pair(s.first-c,make_pair(s.second.first,s.second.second-1)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [488 bytes](https://tio.run/##XVDNisIwGLz7FAFBE5pmFbzlB3wDRQ8tItKmaQ1r026TLnVrn92NVWTZHPLNTCZhMrKuw0LK@32qjby0mWKpdvbDukwGATmLyTRTuTYK7IBVsjLZW4iAJTuS68a6txaP2u7N17DDV5STurVn2NunO5S4j4IOx8F1GBB9m/fAXWvlCagT3TBt3KS12hTAJKWydSIV8LHoHvsTsfFzI7bUuuZhudBvJV3VsCcXKa0bXTXaXU9frWoV24qcWuXYRhR0Cyz1b4ASGyyfKNEGol5qI0QphKF51cBCuYvPBb2KL4j@oygdf3VKE/kJPV/DBV6gxz2aE6t/FPSe3vKcuKr22JcwTp3DSPDFLGK8nMUPFDNuZrPCl2My6PtDnCuPCoT6gmhjVeNGmUqeHqLjIT5yPu/mNArLWxya201WrWNMhq9@fZSlj7KG4XMs8HLcwyUahuF@X4HVhJCOkNfePdZf5Rc "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")